# Why is this piece of Javascript code so slow?

Tags: javascript, profiling, performance

I have this piece of Javascript code, which takes about 600 ms on every call in Internet Explorer. The time taken in other browsers is negligble.

```
var _nvs_currentTab;
var _nvs_zoomfield;
var _nvs_centerfield;
var _nvs_globsearch;
var _nvs_category;
var _nvs_favsonly;
var _nvs_wishonly;
var _nvs_friendfavsonly;
var _nvs_newitemsonly;
var _nvs_globsearchOld;
var _nvs_catOld;
var _nvs_favsonlyOld;
var _nvs_wishonlyOld;
var _nvs_friendFavsonlyOld;
var _nvs_newItemsOnlyOld;

function saveState()
{
    if (!_nvs_currentTab)
    {
        var f = document.getElementById;
        _nvs_currentTab = f('currentTab');
        _nvs_zoomfield = f('zoomfield');
        _nvs_centerfield = f('centerfield');
        _nvs_globsearch = f("globsearch");
        _nvs_category = f("category");
        _nvs_favsonly = f("favsonly");
        _nvs_wishonly = f("wishonly");
        _nvs_friendfavsonly = f("friendfavsonly");
        _nvs_newitemsonly = f("newitemsonly");
        _nvs_globsearchOld = f("globsearchOld");
        _nvs_catOld = f("categoryOld");
        _nvs_favsonlyOld = f("favsonlyOld");
        _nvs_wishonlyOld = f("wishonlyOld");
        _nvs_friendFavsonlyOld = f("friendFavsonlyOld");
        _nvs_newItemsOnlyOld = f("newItemsOnlyOld");
    }

    // get all state vars
    var navState= new Object();
    navState.page = currentPage;
    navState.currentTab = _nvs_currentTab.value;
    navState.zoomfield = _nvs_zoomfield.value;
    navState.centerfield = _nvs_centerfield.value;
    navState.globsearch = _nvs_globsearch.value;
    navState.category = _nvs_category.value;
    navState.favsonly = _nvs_favsonly.checked;
    navState.wishonly = _nvs_wishonly.checked;
    navState.friendfavsonly = _nvs_friendfavsonly.checked;
    navState.newitemsonly = _nvs_newitemsonly.checked;
    navState.globsearchOld = _nvs_globsearchOld.value;
    navState.catOld = _nvs_catOld.value;
    navState.favsonlyOld = _nvs_favsonlyOld.value;
    navState.wishonlyOld = _nvs_wishonlyOld.value;
    navState.friendFavsonlyOld = _nvs_friendFavsonlyOld.value;
    navState.newItemsOnlyOld = _nvs_newItemsOnlyOld.value;
    // build new url with state
    var url = new StringBuffer();
    url.append("#");
    for (var i in navState)
    {
        if (i != "page")
            url.append("&");
        url.append(i).append("=").append(navState[i]);
    }
    // set it
    window.location.href = url.toString();
}
```

This is what the call tree looks like, from the IE8 profiler:

```
saveState               1    615,00 ms
  f                    15      1,00 ms
  String.split          1      0,00 ms
    Array               1      0,00 ms
  Object                1      0,00 ms
  StringBuffer          1      0,00 ms
  append               64      0,00 ms
    Array.push         64      0,00 ms
  toString              1      0,00 ms
    Array.join          1      0,00 ms
  Object.valueOf       63      0,00 ms
  Function.toString    63      0,00 ms
```

The StringBuffer implementation I'm using:

```
function StringBuffer() { 
    this.buffer = []; 
} 

StringBuffer.prototype.append = function append(string) { 
    this.buffer.push(string); 
    return this; 
}; 

StringBuffer.prototype.toString = function toString() { 
    return this.buffer.join(""); 
};
```

**Edit:** Updated code, takes 397 ms on average to run.

```
var _nvs_currentTab;
var _nvs_zoomfield;
var _nvs_centerfield;
var _nvs_globsearch;
var _nvs_category;
var _nvs_favsonly;
var _nvs_wishonly;
var _nvs_friendfavsonly;
var _nvs_newitemsonly;
var _nvs_globsearchOld;
var _nvs_catOld;
var _nvs_favsonlyOld;
var _nvs_wishonlyOld;
var _nvs_friendFavsonlyOld;
var _nvs_newItemsOnlyOld;

function saveState()
{
    if (!_nvs_currentTab)
    {
        var _f = document.guideForm;
        _nvs_currentTab = _f.currentTab;
        _nvs_zoomfield = _f.zoomfield;
        _nvs_centerfield = _f.centerfield;
        _nvs_globsearch = _f.globsearch;
        _nvs_category = _f.category;
        _nvs_favsonly = _f.favsonly;
        _nvs_wishonly = _f.wishonly;
        _nvs_friendfavsonly = _f.friendfavsonly;
        _nvs_newitemsonly = _f.newitemsonly;
        _nvs_globsearchOld = _f.globsearchOld;
        _nvs_catOld = _f.categoryOld;
        _nvs_favsonlyOld = _f.favsonlyOld;
        _nvs_wishonlyOld = _f.wishonlyOld;
        _nvs_friendFavsonlyOld = _f.friendFavsonlyOld;
        _nvs_newItemsOnlyOld = _f.newItemsOnlyOld;
    }

    // build new url with state
    var url = new StringBuffer();
    url.append("#");
    url.append('currentPage=').append(currentPage);
    url.append('&currentTab=').append(_nvs_currentTab.value);
    url.append('&zoomfield=').append(_nvs_zoomfield.value);
    url.append('&centerfield=').append(_nvs_centerfield.value);
    url.append('&globsearch=').append(_nvs_globsearch.value);
    url.append('&category=').append(_nvs_category.value);
    url.append('&favsonly=').append(_nvs_favsonly.checked);
    url.append('&wishonly=').append(_nvs_wishonly.checked);
    url.append('&friendfavsonly=').append(_nvs_friendfavsonly.checked);
    url.append('&newitemsonly=').append(_nvs_newitemsonly.checked);
    url.append('&globsearchOld=').append(_nvs_globsearchOld.value);
    url.append('&catOld=').append(_nvs_catOld.value);
    url.append('&favsonlyOld=').append(_nvs_favsonlyOld.value);
    url.append('&wishonlyOld=').append(_nvs_wishonlyOld.value);
    url.append('&friendFavsonlyOld=').append(_nvs_friendFavsonlyOld.value);
    url.append('&newItemsOnlyOld=').append(_nvs_newItemsOnlyOld.value);
    // set it
    window.location.href = url.toString();
}
```

Comment: Because IE is a whore. /question

Comment: Hah, couldn't agree more! But I think my boss will kill me if I just ignore IE :P

Comment: How much time does it take if you remove the loop? (I know it will stop working but it helps in determining what part is causing the lengthy execution time)

Comment: So your question becomes "how can I convince my boss this will work fine when deployed" :-)

Comment: Removing the loop makes pretty much no difference.

Comment: It's unlikely to - it's just a handful of string ops. I feel something else is going on: something on the page (like a vast DOM), or your tools (what else is watching the DOM and JS?) or PC. Do you have the same behaviour on other PCs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, you're not going to believe this. I just tried removing the following line:

`window.location.href = url.toString();`

And it reduced the average runtime to two third of a millisecond. I know from profiling the toString call is very fast, so apparently setting the window.location.href is ultra slow (couple of hundred ms!!!). Bah, I hate IE.

Note: This is a clean install of Internet Explorer, and I have no crazy toolbars slowing down my browser.

Comment: Possible, but strange. Did you try: `var s = url.toString();`? That would be a proof of slow assigning value to `window.location.href`.

Comment: Yup, tried that. It really is the window.location.href line. I'm searching on Google at the moment, but strangely enough I haven't found anything related yet, though plenty of other weird IE bugs.

Comment: Is there any chance this is tool misreporting then? By changing the href you're essentially taking the legs out from under JS so I imagine all bets could be off with monitoring tools.

Comment: Ugh, just found someone on a blog with the same problem. Apparently it's only this slow if you're running the IE Developer Toolbar. Now how the heck am I going to profile? -_-'

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you store fields from some form.

Instead of using `document.getElementById()` to get each element of form try to get value of form elements directly:

`navState.currentTab = document.formName.currentTab.value;`

where `formName` is value of `name` attribute of `form` tag and `currentTab` is value of `name` attribute of form element (i.e. input, checkbox).

**EDIT:**

When I was using IE5 and IE5.5 in 2000 even change (store reference to form element in variable) from:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.form.elements.length; i++) {
  values[i] = document.form.elements[i].value;
}
```

to:

```
var form = document.form;
for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
  values[i] = form.elements[i].value;
}
```

made big difference.

I am afraid nothing has changed during last 10 years :(.

Comment: Agreed - searching DOM versus direct 'navigation' can give a pretty hearty speed boost.

Comment: Hmm, that saved about 200 ms. Not bad, but still not quite satisfactory. I'll post the updated code in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried commenting out the "get all vars" section and the `window.location.href` line?  It may be one of the `input`s or navigation (e.g. buggy browser toolbar) that's causing the delay.

By the way, it works fine on my test page, but it may be that you have a much larger DOM.