# window.location.hash assignation painfully slow in IE8

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer

i'm having trouble with modifying the location hash in IE8 for XP. simply calling:

```
self.location.hash = "whatever"
```

takes about 800ms~1800ms

I have no idea what can slow this down. I checked the same instruction on some other sites and it's not that slow.

Any clues what can make it so slow ? I am sorry but I can't give an online example.

---

EDIT:
Here's What I get in the IE console, input:

```
console.log( new Date().getTime() );
self.location.hash = "sfdsd";
console.log( new Date().getTime() );
```

output:

```
JOURNAL : 1326468325447
JOURNAL : 1326468327390
undefined
```

which makes almost 2000ms, if I read correctly, for a single assignation :/ .

---

EDIT2: since it doesn't seem clear enough, more preofiled code:

```
var profileThat = function() {self.location.hash = "whatever"};
$('#keywatchHeader').click( profileThat );
```

profiler results with two clicks:

> ```
> profileThat   2   3475,00 3475,00
> hidden    4   50,07   50,07   http://192.168.0.30/kw5/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js   6 608   
> eventHandle   8   3525,07 40,06   http://192.168.0.30/kw5/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js   2 595   
> get   4   20,03   20,03   http://192.168.0.30/kw5/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js   6 419   
> get   6   10,01   10,01   http://192.168.0.30/kw5/js/yui2/dom/dom.js  96
> ```

---

EDIT3:

I ran some tests on node number on tree out of curiosity and results are surprising. After such a call:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*').length; //3621
$('#keywatchPanels').children().remove();
document.getElementsByTagName('*').length; //332
```

after that the profiler gives **600ms** instead of **1700ms** per call! But I hardly with node number would influence hashtag writing.

---

(edit4):I've found this related question: [Why is this piece of Javascript code so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833441/why-is-this-piece-of-javascript-code-so-slow) (but the answer here is just "remove it")

Comment: How large is your page? Any other code that is running checking the hash?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by large ? pixel width, weight,elements? There is the YUI2 history manager which is checking the hash but it's solely this instruction who sucks that much time, whether I exect it in code, or console.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Takes around 100ms here on IE8.0.6001.18702. How did you measure the performance? Did you use the [IE script profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_start)?

Comment: both by IE script profiler and "perception". It literaly takes a second from time I hit enter in the console, and the time the result come. Same when I debug step by step. As I said, I tried on other sites but only my app is that slow.

Comment: and what was the output of the profiler. which functions where invoked?

Comment: as previously stated, this ain't a function call, this is an asignment: self.location.hash = "whatever". I made a second example to made it more clearer.

Comment: Can you try including the initial '#', too? Could be, that IE chokes on inserting it itself. (Reading location.hash includes the '#'.)

Comment: I just tried, IE8 doesn't include the "#" twice but the profiled time is still 1700ms. I also tried with window.location.href, same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally, i've found my answer in a comment of an answer of a related question:
[Why is this piece of Javascript code so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833441/why-is-this-piece-of-javascript-code-so-slow)

> Ugh, just found someone on a blog with the same problem. Apparently
>   it's only this slow if you're running the IE Developer Toolbar. Now
>   how the heck am I going to profile? -_-'

– Aistina May 7 '09 at 9:22

Why didn't I though about it earlier ?

Comment: You can still profile by recording the time before changing the location.hash and the time after it has changed and alert the difference (like in your question above). The time difference for me is anywhere between 400ms to 600ms which I consider as pretty high. Have you found any solution to the slowness yet?

Comment: No answer different than closing the debugger. Like I mentionned in the question(see EDIT 3), reducing your page charge (by removing all elements) did reduce the response time. But at this point this is more religion than science.